# AVAudioPlayer causing memory leak? Release memory?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, memory-leaks, avaudioplayer

My Xcode app plays many different audio files. There seems to be a memory leak that eventually crashes the app. Should I be releasing the memory of the audio players? What extra code do I need to release these? I have about 400 audio files.

```
NSString *file1Path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"50"ofType:@"mp3"];
NSURL *file1URL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:file1Path];
file1Player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:file1URL error:nil];
[file1Player play];
```

could I just add this code?

```
-(void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag
{
    [file1Player release];
    file1Player=nil;

}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. 1, no I have not set the delegate for the player. I will do that. Next I would have to set the `file1Player.delegate = self;` correct? Do I add this statement in every audio player block? 2. I don't want to use a manual release, but I don't know how else to fix the memory issue. 3. I tried the analyzer, yes many leaks, based on the audio player setup.

Comment: Thanks. I was using an old app to create a new one and it didn't have arc turned on. This might be the whole issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have proposed adding `[file1Player release]`.

If you are using automatic reference counting, that is not only not necessary, but not permitted. If you are using manual reference counting, though, it is essential. But make sure to specify the `delegate` of the `AVAudioPlayer` or else that method won’t be called.

If you are using manual reference counting, I’d suggest using <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> (or “Product” » “Analyze”) to perform static analysis. Especially in manual reference counting code (but even in ARC Objective-C code), this static analyzer is an extremely useful tool. There is no point in proceeding until you’ve resolved all issues identified there.

Or, as you suggest, even better, convert your manual reference counting project to automatic reference counting.

Comment: Thanks. I changed to ARC and removed manual release. I think it fixed the problem.